# Call PHP variable within MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I m retrieving a url from Mysql which contains Php varibale.

```
<?php


$mysqli=new mysqli("127.0.0.1","uname","pass","tab1");
if($mysqli === false){
 die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$oid = 104;
$code = 1045;
$id1 = 100006;

$qry = "select link1 from tab1 where oid=".$oid.";";
$result = $mysqli->query($qry);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo $row['link1'];

?>
```

```
link1 --> https://mydomain/index.php?id1=$code&id2=$id1
```

When i execute this i m getting the full url as it is without getting the variable value,
any ideas on how to call the variable ?

Comment: Luckily, MySQL will not try to run as code everything you retrieve from database. You can [replace](https://www.php.net/str_replace) `$code` in your string but I really suggest you rethink your overall design.

Comment: @SomangshuGoswami, i m not inserting variables into the database, i m retrieving it.

Comment: Check the select statement at the end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have retrieved from your SQL is a *string*. The same symbols are there but it's not actually a variable reference.

What you need to do is then insert these variable references. So;

## Code:

```
/***
 * Note the use of single quotes here
 ***/
$find = ['$code','$id1'];
$replace = [$code,$id1];
$output = str_replace($find,$replace,$row['link1']);
print $output;
```

## Output:

> link1 --> https://mydomain/index.php?id1=$code&id2=$id1
>   output --> https://mydomain/index.php?id1=1045&id2=100006

## Important:

What [Álvaro González says](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13508/%c3%81lvaro-gonz%c3%a1lez) is absolutely true:

> Luckily, MySQL will not try to run as code everything you retrieve from database. You can replace $code in your string but I really suggest **you rethink your overall design**.

(my emphesis)